# Diffusion process and jump process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I am reading diffusion process from a textbook and noticed that the author claims that condition (1) implies the stochastic process $X_{t}$ cannot have instantaneous jumps. So I wonder does "cannot have instantaneous jumps" implies $X_t$ is continuous in $t$? And why is it true? Moreover, can I show it using $\epsilon-\delta$ language?

> Definition 10.8.3. An $\mathbb{R}^{n}$-valued Markov process $X_{t}, a \leq t \leq b$, is called a diffusion process if its transition probabilities $\left\{P_{s, x}(t, \cdot)\right\}$ satisfy the following three conditions for any $t \in[a, b], x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $c>0$ :
> (1) $\lim _{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{|y-x| \geq c} P_{t, x}(t+\varepsilon, d y)=0$.
> (2) $\lim _{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{|y-x|<c}\left(y_{i}-x_{i}\right) P_{t, x}(t+\varepsilon, d y)=\rho_{i}(t, x)$ exists.
> (3) $\lim _{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{|y-x|<c}\left(y_{i}-x_{i}\right)\left(y_{j}-x_{j}\right) P_{t, x}(t+\varepsilon, d y)=Q_{i j}(t, x)$ exists.
> Remark 10.8.4. Condition (1) implies that the stochastic process $X_{t}$ cannot have instantaneous jumps.

Comment: Try to compare the property with a Continuous time Markov chain.

Comment: I tried to think of this CTMC, but didn't prove it. Would you show more detailed steps ?

Comment: What textbook are you using ?

Comment: $\textbf{Introduction to Stochastic Integration}$ written by Hui-Hsiung Kuo.

Comment: I wasn't so successful in finding a solution. I tried to approach a different notation found in Applied Stochastic Processes by Mario Lefebvre. The notation is $$\lim _{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\mathbb P\left[|X(t+\varepsilon)-X(t)|>\delta|X(t)=x\right]=0$$. I suggest you try to apply Markov's conditional inequality. It would lead to something from there.